# Converting a MSSQL Datestamp to BIGINT for UNIX

Tags: sql-server, unix, timestamp, bigint

I've been having trouble with something i cannot quite get my head around and I was wondering if you can help?

On my table, i have a column called

> ADDEDDATE

This column shows the date in which an incident or ticket was added to the database table and its formatting is shown as the following example:

```
2015-08-25 09:58:14.967
```

I want to convert this to UNIX timestamp so first i have performed the following:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, ADDEDDATE) AS 'UNIX DATE ADDED' FROM dbo.TABLE
```

Running this I get integer values such as "1147855575". Now I understand in order to make this work on UNIX timestamp i need to use BIGINT to convert, so i wrote the following:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, ADDEDDATE) AS 'UNIX DATE ADDED',
CASE CAST(SUM('UNIX DATE ADDED' AS BIGINT) FROM dbo.TABLE
```

This returned an error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
>   'SUM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

So i did some googling and searching through Stackoverflow and found i did the second line wrong, it should look like:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, ADDEDDATE) AS 'UNIX DATE ADDED',
CASE CAST(BIGINT,'UNIX DATE ADDED') FROM dbo.TABLE
```

However this too fails with the following message:

> Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.

Can someone please assist me in trying to convert an entire column of integer data to BIGINT for UNIX Datestamp? I am using MSSQL (SSMS 2014).

Comment: simply `datediff(second, '1970-01-01', ADDEDDATE)`

Comment: The case, incorrectly placed before the cast. may be what you want is SELECT cast(DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, ADDEDDATE) as bigint) AS 'UNIX DATE ADDED' FROM dbo.TABLE

Comment: Ahmed Saeed, unfortunately your solution returns the exact same 10 number long result as the original SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, ADDEDDATE) AS 'UNIX DATE ADDED'. Squirrel can you please expand on your explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01', ADDEDDATE) AS bigint) AS 'UNIX DATE ADDED' FROM dbo.TABLE;
```

When you'll migrate on SQL Server 2016, you'll be able to use [DATEDIFF_BIG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql)